# How to reverse characters in a string keeping digits at the original index?

Tags: haskell

I have recently started learning Haskell. I am trying to reverse a string which contains chars and numbers. The string is to be reversed keeping digits at the original place.

> Original String = "H1AW2J1"
>
> Reversed = J1WA2H1

I am trying to follow the pattern which I used in Swift.

1. filter digits and then reverse the string.
2. find the index of digits in the original string.
3. insert the digits at index obtained from step 2 into the string from step 1.

Below are the codes following above steps.

**reversedChars "H1AW2J1" retuns  "JWAH"**

```
reversedChars  = reverse . filter isLetter
```

**Indexes returns tuples.**

```
indexes xs = [(x, elemIndex x xs) | x <- xs]
```

> [('H',Just 0),('1',Just 1),('A',Just 2),('W',Just 3),('2',Just 4),('J',Just 5),('1',Just 1)]

**Questions**

1. How to insert digits at the repective index into `reversedChars`
2. `elemIndex` is returning same index `Just 1` for multiple occurrence of 1.

Comment: Lists are a suboptimal choice for this problem, if you are allowed I would use `Data.Sequence` for inserting at a given index, otherwise I would go on and use `Data.List.groupBy` and `length` to get a list of building blocks, reverse the letters and partition by those lengths and insert the letters by zipping it.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/gunPgg) is a version that can reverse an infinite list and keep digits available for lookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. How to insert digits at the repective index into `reversedChars`

I would use a recursive function like this, which inserts the next reversed char if it encounters a letter, otherwise just inserts the actual character:

```
import Data.Char

reverseLetters :: String -> String
reverseLetters xs = go xs (reverse $ filter isLetter $ xs)
  where
    go xs [] = xs
    go (x:xs) (r:rs) | isLetter x = r : go xs rs
                     | otherwise  = x : go xs (r:rs)

main = print $ reverseLetters "H1AW2J1"
```

Output:

```
"J1WA2H1"
```

> 2. `elemIndex` is returning same index `Just 1` for multiple occurrence of 1.

That's because that is what `elemIndex` is defined to return. If you want all indices, you can do:

```
Prelude> map fst $ filter ((== '1') . snd) $ zip [0..] "H1AW2J1"
[1,6]
```

Comment: One quibble: they asked for non-digits to be reversed. Your code reverses letters. The solution, of course, is simply to use `not . isDigit` instead of `isLetter`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would also look similar to @Dogbert's however here is one that implements it the way you approached the problem.

There is no `update` function for lists in the standard library and even if there was, it would not be a good idea to use it, as it would have O(n) where n is the index, because lists are singly linked lists. Instead you have to write your own function to include the numbers back into the string:

```
reverseChars :: [Char] -> [Char]
reverseChars cs = insert reversedChars digits
  where reversedChars = reverse $ filter isLetter cs
        digits = filter (\(_,c) -> isDigit c) $ indexes cs

insert :: [a] -> [(Int, a)] -> [a]
insert = go 0
  where go i (x:xs) ((j,y):ys)
          | j > i = x : go (i+1) xs ((j,y):ys)
          | otherwise = y : go (i+1) (x:xs) ys
        go _ xs [] = xs
        go _ [] ys = map snd ys

indexes :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
indexes = zip [0..]
```

I have also changed the implementation of indexes, because `elemIndex` also has complexity O(n) with n being the position of the searched-for element in the list, so your indexes function would have O(n²). Furthermore with this implementation you get rid of the `Maybe` in `indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach does away with having to find the indices of individual elements:

```
reverseIf :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
reverseIf f = fill <*> reverse . filter f
  where fill s []     = s
        fill (s:ss) (r:rs)
          | f s       = x : fill ss rs
          | otherwise = s : fill ss (r:rs)
```

Here is another version:

```
reverseIf :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
reverseIf f = snd . (flip (mapAccumL g) <*> reverse . filter f)
  where g r e | f e       = (tail r, head r)
              | otherwise = (r, e)
```

Invocation:

```
> reverseIf (not . isDigit) "H1AW2J1"
"J1WA2H1"
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as Dogbert's, with a more general predicate? Note that your type signature isn't as general as it could be. `reverseIf :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, I only noticed it after posting the answer. Since mine is implemented slightly differently (I aimed to make it pointfree, with use of existing abstractions -- `<*>` and `mapAccumL`) I left the answer as is for what it is worth. I have modified the code with your suggestion.

Comment: Your second version is incomprehensible and uses partial functions. What exactly does it have to say for itself? You could (arguably) justify that by making this work with any `Traversable`.

Comment: The second version uses `mapAccumL` which takes the iteration responsibility from the (earlier) `fill` function so comparatively little user code needs to be written. Otherwise it achieves the same.